# drush variable-set for permission table

Tags: 6, drush

I want to enable `access comments`, `post comments`, and `post comments without approval` for anonymous using drush.

Fresh install, the table entry look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `permission` VALUES (2,2,'access comments, access content, post comments, post comments without approval',0);
```

After `access comments`, `post comments`, and `post comments without approval` enabled for anonymous, it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `permission` VALUES (3,1,'access comments, post comments, post comments without approval, access content',0);
INSERT INTO `permission` VALUES (4,2,'access comments, post comments, post comments without approval, access content',0);
```

I can use `drush variable-set error_level "0"` to change error reporting level. But how about above case? It looks more difficult to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no explicit command to run in order to grant a role a certain permission. The documentation is very helpful here - http://www.drush.org/help/5

However, you can use drush to execute native SQL in order to solve the issue

e.g.

```
drush sql-query "INSERT INTO permission VALUES (4,2,'access comments, post comments, post comments without approval, access content',0)"
```

If this is something you will be doing on a regular basis after a site install, consider creating your own custom install profile (which will contain the required SQL, or features), or creating your own custom module (e.g. created using features). I imagine having to run this script over CLI is not the most maintainable solution ;)

Comment: Thanks, but it not works. I think something wrong at the `4,2`. I tried `9,1` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Permissions API](http://drupal.org/node/802272)'s Drush commands.

Comment: If you follow that link, it gives you help to setting permissions via drush. It just requires that you install the permissions_api module first.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this post and using Drupal 7, you have two choices.

1.Using SQL, you can run the following

```
drush sql-query "INSERT INTO role_permission VALUES (<role id>,'<permission>','<module>')";
```

e.g.

```
drush sql-query "INSERT INTO role_permission VALUES (1,'access comments','comments')"
```

or

2.Using the [Permissions API module](http://drupal.org/project/permissions_api), you can run the following:

```
drush -u 1 perm-grant --roles="anonymous user" --permissions="access comments"
```